# Prevent two tables from being joined

Tags: sql-server

Is there a means in SQL server to prevent two tables from being joined together?

Considering two separate sets of logins, where each login has access to a different set of data to prevent joining the tables in SQL.

Comment: Only if they have no common column or data on which to join.

Comment: If you have 2 logins and only give each access to one table they won't be able to query the 2nd table if that is what you are asking. You could do this with a schema, or role based permissions which allow access to only specific tables. So I think the answer is yes?

Comment: Can I use one login and create the separation with schemas?

Comment: You should see `GRANT` and `DENY`